# Laravel edit routing best practice

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In laravel 5.2 basic task list tutorial there are three routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () { /**/ });
Route::post('/task', function (Request $request) { /**/ });
Route::delete('/task/{task}', function (Task $task) { /**/ });
```

The first is for listing tasks, the second for adding a task and the last for deleting a task. In the tutorial the listing view contain also the form for adding a task.

Which is the best practice for having a separate page that contain the form for add/edit tasks? I'm thinking about something like this:

```
Route::get('/edit/{task?}', function () { /**/ });
```

Using the optional {task?} parameter I can choose if it's an insert or an update, but I don't like so much specifying the action (edit) inside the URL.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice for CRUD in Laravel is to create [resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers):

```
php artisan make:controller TaskController --resource
```

And use `Route::resource()` for routes. For example, this clause will create 7 standard routes for CRUD:

```
Route::resource('task', 'TaskController');
```

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately I'm working on an existing controller, so I have to write my own routes, but I can steal the logic from here.